# connect to ftp server with tunneling trough vpn in Nextcloud

Tags: vpn, ftp, nextcloud, openconnect

My main goal is to bind an external ftp storage in my Nextcloud. I can't access the ftp storage directly, so I have to use a vpn.
I tried to connect to the vpn, but it failed:

```
openconnect -u User --authenticate vpn-server.org --usergroup=OutsideAC --protocol=anyconnect --cafile=ca.pem
```

First question: Is this command correct, or could this result in connection problems to my Nextcloud from my computer? (Not all trafic should go trough the vpn, only the traffic to the ftp server)

When running to command, I get this output:

```
POST https://vpn-server.org/OutsideAC
Connected to 145.80.212.13:443
SSL negotiation with vpn-server.org
Connected to HTTPS on vpn-server.org
XML POST enabled
Invalid host entry. Please re-enter.
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

I have tried serveral options too (such as `-v` and `--os=...`), but the vpn doesn't work. The ftp Server is not reachable. I looked also in the folder `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, but this folder is empty.

How can I fix this issue? And have a permanent ftp connection via vpn (reconnect automatically after reboot)